# based on current date- sort json data on button click

Tags: angularjs, json

I am using angularJs for developing an Hybrid Mobile App for IOS and Android. I am getting JSON data like :

```
[{"EventId":101,"Title":"No title","Date":"9/8/2015","Time":"12:00 AM","Location":""},{"EventId":120,"Title":"My First Event","Date":"9/15/2015","Time":"12:00 AM","Location":""}]
```

My question is that I have one button, click on that button I need to short my data based on current date. If i click on a button it should show me only that record that matched the current date.

I tried to follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25349940/how-to-filter-json-data-based-on-current-date) but it is not working.

Code :

```
 $scope.Schedule = [{"EventId":101,"Title":"No title","Date":"9/8/2015","Time":"12:00 AM","Location":""},{"EventId":120,"Title":"My First Event","Date":"9/15/2015","Time":"12:00 AM","Location":""}];

  <ion-content>   
        <ul ng-repeat="member in Schedule">
            <li class="item">
                <div class="item" style="border-width: 0px; padding : 1px;">{{member.Title}}</div> 
                <div class="item" style="border-width: 0px; padding : 1px;">{{member.Location}}</div>
                <div class="item" style="border-width: 0px; padding : 1px;">{{member.Time}}{{member.Date}}</div> 
            </li>  
        </ul>  
    </ion-content>
    <ion-footer-bar align-title="left" class="bar-assertive">  
    <div class="list"> 
        <a ng-click="setOrder()"> Show today's </a>
    </div>
    </ion-footer-bar>
```

Comment: Can you share the code please?

Comment: I updated with code @xxlali

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [working plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/nxsxJcOD0MA9WR3o0SHf?p=preview)

**Markup**

```
<button ng-show="curDate == ''" type="button" ng-click="filterByCurDate()">Filter By Current Date</button>
<button ng-hide="curDate == ''" type="button" ng-click="curDate = ''">Clear Filter</button>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>EventId</th>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Date</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="event in events | filter: {Date: curDate}">
      <td>{{event.EventId}}</td>
      <td>{{event.Title}}</td>
      <td>{{event.Date}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Controller Code**

```
$scope.curDate = '';
$scope.filterByCurDate = function() {
  var now = new Date();
  $scope.curDate = $filter('date')(now, 'M/dd/yyyy');
};

$scope.events = [...];
```

Comment: can I do toggle for this, because it is hiding everything click on button if there no item for the same.

Comment: Yes. I can update the plnkr. But is this filter what you were looking for?

Comment: Yes, I am looking for this only.

Comment: @VishalSingh [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/nxsxJcOD0MA9WR3o0SHf?p=preview) is updated with a "toggle"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to order records based on date field use **orderBy** predicate instead of **filter**

***Asc*** order

```
<ANY ng-repeat="record in records | orderBy:'Date'">..</ANY>
```

***Desc*** order

```
<ANY ng-repeat="record in records | orderBy:'-Date'">..</ANY>
```

[Angular DOC: orderBy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy)

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
  var today = new Date(),
  jsonData = JSON.parse('[{"EventId":101,"Title":"No title","Date":"9/8/2015","Time":"12:00 AM","Location":""},{"EventId":120,"Title":"My First Event","Date":"1/29/2016","Time":"12:00 AM","Location":""}]');

  today.setHours(0,0,0,0); //we don't need time to compare

  jsonData.forEach(function(entry) {
    entry.Date = new Date(entry.Date);

    if (entry.Date.valueOf()===today.valueOf()){
      console.log("Pass: "+entry);
    }
  });
```